Code to subscribe to transactions calling a specific instruction in Token Program Solana?
I would like to receive transactions only if the Token Program: SyncNative instruction is called, not on all instructions of a given program. Could you help me with the code to solve this problem?

Using the base websocket API provided with the Solana RPC, you'll need to subscribe to all logs for the token program, which is at address TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, using the logsSubscribe endpoint https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe.
If you want to see all calls to SyncNative, you'll need to search specifically for the line Instruction: SyncNative in the logs: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/f0b0ced617a4ae9b36bcc612c83c3ddac0a94454/token/program/src/processor.rs#L943
